# Proving that if $2a + 3b \ge 12m + 1$, then $a \ge 3m + 1$ or $b \ge 2m + 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

> Let $a$, $b$, $m$ be integers. Prove that if $2a + 3b \ge 12m + 1$, then $a \ge 3m + 1$ or $b \ge 2m + 1$.

I need help proving this. I am not sure what to do.

Thank you for all of the edits.

I am still unsure on how to word the problem.

---

Right now.

Proof -
By contrapositive.

Assume that a < 3m + 1 and b < 2m + 1 for the integers a, b, and m. Then,

2a + 3b < 12m + 1 = 2(3m + 1) + 3(2m+1) < 12 m + 1

= 6m + 2 + 6m + 3 < 12m + 1
= 12m + 5 < 12m + 1

Which is false because 5 < 1

So next, I would say...

Assume that a < 3m + 1 and b < 2m + 1 for the integers a, b, and m. Then
a < 3m < 3m + 1 and b < 2m < 2m + 1.

Then plug in again to show
12m < 12m + 1

Then what?

Comment: New information

Answer (score 2):

Hint: What happens if $a \le 3m$ and $b \le 2m$?

Comment: Why would they ever equal that because the opposite would be a < 3m and b < 2m

I was going to do this proof by contra-positive if that is correct?

Comment: @JonathanY. Everything is integers.

Comment: The negation of $a \ge 3m+1$ is $a < 3m+1$, but since $a$ is an integer, this is the same as $a \le 3m$.

Comment: @Proofs, yes, that would be correct. In the future, if you have a method in mind, please describe what you've done and/or planning to do in the question body.

Comment: Ok, I apologize. I am new to the website. 

So I would assume
that a < 3m + 1 and b < 3m + 1 for some integers a, b, m? Correct?

Comment: @Proofs Reread mrf's comment

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: [Proof by contrapositve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contrapositive).

Proof - By contrapositive.

Assume that $a < 3m + 1$ and $b < 2m + 1$ for the integers $a, b$ and $m$.
Then $a \le 3m$ and $b \le 2m$ since $a,b,m$ are integers. 
And then $2a + 3b \le 12m$. Thus $2a + 3b < 12m + 1$.

Comment: That is the answer?

I feel that I am over thinking these.